# Determine whether ActionScript method called using super

Tags: actionscript-3, super

I have a method which logs a message each time it is called. I would like this log message to indicate whether the method was called directly or invoked using `super` in a child class.

```js
class DoerOfWork {
    public function doWork():void {
        var calledWithSuper:Boolean; 

        calledWithSuper = ???;

        trace("doWork called" + (calledWithSuper ? " (with super)." : "."));
    }
}

class SlowerDoerOfWork extends DoerOfWork {
    public override function doWork():void {
        for (var i:Number = 0; i < 321684; i++) {
            // wait a moment
        }
        super.doWork();
    }
}
```

I hoped it would be possible to determine whether the class of `this` had overridden the implementation of `doWork` by comparing `this.doWork` to `DoerOfWork.prototype.doWork`.

Unfortunately this isn't possible. Unbound methods are not accessible anywhere in ActionScript (the specification lists two types of functions: function closures and bound methods). There don't even to be any properties on instances on `MethodClosure` that could identify whether two are bound copies of the same method.

How can I check if a method has been overridden or use any other method to determine whether the currently-executing ActionScript method was called using `super` or called directly?

Answer (score 3):

You can get a reference to the currently-executing function as `arguments.callee`. From the method this will be the `MethodClosure` of `DoerOfWork().doWork()` with `this`. If `doWork()` hasn't been overridden this will be equal to `this.doWork`.

```
class DoerOfWork {
    public function doWork():void {
        var calledWithSuper:Boolean; 

        calledWithSuper = this.doWork == arguments.callee;

        trace("doWork called" + (calledWithSuper ? " (with super)." : "."));
    }
}
```

If you're running in non-strict mode, apparently this will disable argument count checking for the current function. (I haven't checked this myself, I'm not even sure how to disable strict mode in IntelliJ.)

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to use `flash.utils.describeType()`, it contains the information we need:

```xml
<type name="Main.as$1::SlowerDoerOfWork" base="Main.as$1::DoerOfWork"
      isDynamic="false" isFinal="false" isStatic="false">
  <extendsClass type="Main.as$1::DoerOfWork"/>
  <extendsClass type="Object"/>
  <method name="doWork" declaredBy="Main.as$1::SlowerDoerOfWork"
          returnType="void">
    <metadata name="__go_to_definition_help">
      <arg key="pos" value="1170"/>
    </metadata>
  </method>
  <metadata name="__go_to_definition_help">
    <arg key="pos" value="1103"/>
  </metadata>
</type>
```

The `declaredBy` attribute of each `<method>` in the XML uses the same format as `flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName`, and we can compare these to determine if our implementation was overridden.

```
class DoerOfWork {
    public function doWork():void {
        var calledWithSuper:Boolean; 

        var currentImplementationFrom:String
          = flash.utils.describeType(this).method.(@name=="doWork").@declaredBy;
        var thisImplementationFrom:String
          = flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(DoerOfWork);

        calledWithSuper = currentImplementationFrom != thisImplementationFrom;

        trace("doWork called" + (calledWithSuper ? " (with super)." : "."));
    }
}
```